# Responsive table in height attribute html?

Tags: html, css, height

I am trying to make a table so that its height is responsive. I want the height of the table to be down to the bottom of the page, and its cells should redistribute the space of the table. I know that with the width property I can set %, but when I do it with height it doesn't work. This is the code:

CSS:

```
#days_table{
width: 100%;
height: auto;}

.d_td{
text-align: center;
width: 10%;
height: 10%;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="row2">
        <table id="days_table">
            <!-- for 3 times -->
            <tr>
                <!-- for 10 times -->
                <td class="d_td">1</td>
                <td class="d_td">2</td>
                <td class="d_td">3</td>
                <td class="d_td">4</td>
                <td class="d_td">5</td>
                <td class="d_td">6</td>
                <td class="d_td">7</td>
                <td class="d_td">8</td>
                <td class="d_td">9</td>
                <td class="d_td">10</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set #days_table height: 100vh

Comment: Thanks. It causes a acceptable result. I use a value of 60vh instead, because I have more things in my page. Maybe is there another way, which causes that the remaining space be occupied by the table?

Comment: Can you show me the mockup layout that you want? "remaining space be occupied by the table" mean table height is still 100vh but you want 60vh for one row and 40vh for another row?

Comment: I mean I wanted the table height occupy the remaining of the height of the web page in the screen